# -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation related message

Tags: ios4, uiinterfaceorientation

Here is something strange concerning AutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

In the Debugger console I get this message for one of my view controllers :

***The view controller  returned NO from
-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.***

But in reality the rotations works perfectly well. And the message is wrong. Here is the code for -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return ([centerPoint autoRotateFlag]||(interfaceOrientation==centerPoint.userOrientation));
}
```

And either autoRotateFlag is simply true (YES), or if it is not centerPoint.userOrientation has been fixed to one of the four acceptable value.

This has been working for me for a long time and the app still works. I just don't know where this message is coming from.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

By putting some tracing in my software, using NSLog; I realized that
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation was called seven times before
viewDidLoad was called.

Since my variable 'autoRotateFlag' is only initialized when passing through viewDidLoad. That explains my problem.

I have to admit though, that I was far from thinking shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation could be called before viewDidLoad.
Obviously I was wrong. And I still do not fully understand the order in which all those methods are called.